# Select distinct on one column but return all columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

My aim is to use distinct on one column but return all the columns.

My table is like this

```
id, name, year

1, John, 2012

2, Jake, 2012

3, Jenna, 2013

1, John, 2013
```

I need to do distinct on id column and return all the three columns as well as not same id's, I need to most recent record.

Output I need is

```
id, name, year

1, John, 2013

2, Jake, 2012

3, Jenna, 2013
```

I have tried these two commands

1. select distinct id, name, year from sampletable.
   I will do distinct on all the rows.
2. select * from sampletable group by id
   I will only return id column and drop the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Using the windowing and analytic functions you can partition the data by the id ordering by the year, and choosing the first result:

```
SELECT id, name, year
FROM 
 (SELECT id, name, year, row_number() over (partition by id order by year desc) as r 
  FROM sampletable) S 
WHERE S.r = 1;
```

Plus there are other ranking functions such as `rank` and `dense_rank` for different selections.

Answer (score 0):

without analytic functions

```
    select t.id, t.name, t.year from t
    join
      (select id, max(year) year from t group by id) as S 
      on S.id=t.id and S.year = t.year
```

;